# Can't add theme translation for prestashop

Tags: cloud, prestashop, translation, public

I created the Prestashop Certified by Bitnami version 1.7.6.2 project on google public cloud and when I want to translate the template I get errors:

> Impossible to copy
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/htdocs/translations/en/admin.php" to
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/htdocs/translations/pl/admin.php".
>   Impossible to copy
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/htdocs/translations/en/errors.php" to
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/htdocs/translations/pl/errors.php".
>   Impossible to copy
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/htdocs/translations/en/fields.php" to
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/htdocs/translations/pl/fields.php".
>   Impossible to copy
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/htdocs/translations/en/pdf.php" to
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/htdocs/translations/pl/pdf.php".
>   Impossible to copy
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/htdocs/translations/en/tabs.php" to
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/htdocs/translations/pl/tabs.php".
>   Impossible to copy
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/htdocs/mails/en/lang.php" to
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/htdocs/mails/pl/lang.php". Cannot create
>   the folder
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/htdocs/themes/classic/lang/pl.php".
>   Please check your directory writing permissions. A part of the data
>   has been copied but some of the language files could not be found.

And if I want to change the language of the administrator panel the message "updated successfully" appears but nothing changes. I was looking for answers everywhere but to no avail, maybe someone will help here

Comment: Check the permissions of the folders in you  Prestashop instance they should have 0777 to be available to be written

Comment: Ok, but how can I find folder if my instance is on google cloud platform, I don't have access to the folders

Comment: Never set chmod 777